# is there any way i can get a js event or function when i edit cells in Datasheet/Quick edit view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, view, datasheet, quick-edit

I need apply some client side changes when i click on cells for editing. i wanted to know if there is certain javascript event or functions which i can use to apply the changes through javascript/jQuery

Comment: is there any way to seek microsoft documentation about js events ?

Comment: it is really hard to catch just a tiny fish in the ocean and right now i think i'm looking for a mermaid ;) i've tried and failed to get answer that is why i asked for direct help